# camel invoke third party webservice

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to the Fuse-camel,cxf.

i wan to invoke third party webservice. i don't want to use wsld2java or serviceclass. I have a wsdl.

Here is the requirement to make generic webservice call

json request data-->generate soap request --> cxf:endpoint in PAYLOAD format-->soap response -->json response data  to client.

1 . how do i convert json to soaprequest(xml) and vice-versa ( Marshall-format-soapjxab is expecting jaxb annotated classes) 
2.how do I call in soap in payload mode..

any help (link/example) is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Narendra

Comment: 1. Start with reading the documentation. 2. Try an example and then if you run into specific issues ask that specific question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Camel CXFRS](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) to set up rest endpoints.
2. On parsing the JSON, set the values to JAXB annotated POJO's.
3. Then use [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) to send SOAP request to third party service.
4. On receiving the response you can unmarshal it, either using JAXB unmarshaller in java code or incase of DSL use [Camel JAXB DataFormat](http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html)
5. Route the response to the client by setting the content in camel exchange.